# Nested tab navigator with header

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to achieve something similar to the image below.

[image]

Basically, I want to have a nested tab navigator and place it under a custom header. The main tab navigator is the one at the bottom. The nested tab navigator is the one on the top with "Recent, Tab2, Tab3". I'm all set till here, but I can't get the nested navigator to place itself under the custom header. Is there any way that I can do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code of the navigators:

```
const TopNav = TabNavigator(
  {
    Recent: { screen: Recent },
    Tab2: { screen: Tab2 },
    Tab3: { screen: Tab3 },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#f67425",
      activeBackgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      inactiveTintColor: "#4a4a4a",
      inactiveBackgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      // showLabel: false,
    },
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    initialRouteName: "Messages",
    tabBarPosition: "top",
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: false,
  }
);

const BottomNav = TabNavigator(
  {
    Search: { screen: Search },
    Messages: { screen: TopNav },
    Contacts: { screen: Contacts },
    More: { screen: More },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#f67425",
      activeBackgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      inactiveTintColor: "#4a4a4a",
      inactiveBackgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      // showLabel: false,
    },
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    initialRouteName: "Messages",
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    swipeEnabled: false,
  }
);
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/wix/react-native-custom-segmented-control)

Comment: @PPL I want something that functions the same as react navigation tab navigator - to go through tabs. With this I have to load all three tabs' content and then go through them using states - I'm really trying to avoid that. Otherwise, writing a custom component for this purpose is much easier (for some reason I can't get the package to work properly)!